# Laravel form for creating user not working without error

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am stuck with a form that is not working. I get an error that says:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field `firstname` doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`role`) values (user)).

Except that it isn't inserting the data in the database either. PLEASE HELP!!

```
<?php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint; use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;class CreateUsersTable extendsMigration{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('suffix')->nullable();
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->integer('phoneNumber');
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('streetName');
        $table->integer('streetNumber');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('zipcode');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'UsersAdminController@store']) !!}
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('firstname', 'First name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('firstname', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('suffix', 'Suffix:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('suffix', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('lastname', 'Last name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('lastname', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('city', 'City:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('zipcode', 'Zipcode:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('zipcode', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('phoneNumber', 'Phone number:') !!}
            {!! Form::number('phoneNumber', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('streetName', 'Street name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('streetName', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('streetNumber', 'Street number:') !!}
            {!! Form::number('streetNumber', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail:') !!}
            {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
               {!! Form::submit('Create User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and my controller:

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    if(trim($request->password) == '')
    {
        $input = $request->except('password');

    }else{

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
//$input['role'] = 'user';

        DB::table('users')->insert(
            ['role' => 'user']
        );

    }

    User::create($input);

    return back()->with('success' , 'User is succesfully created');

}
```

and this is my validation in a request file:

```
class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'firstname' => 'required',
        'suffix' => 'string',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'phoneNumber' => 'required',
        'streetName' => 'required',
        'streetNumber' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'zipcode' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];
}
}
```

also this is my user models mass assignment:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname','suffix','lastname', 'phoneNumber', 'role', 'streetName', 'streetNumber', 'city', 'zipcode' ,'email', 'password',
];
```

Comment: Can you die and dump $request please and post it?

Comment: `DB::table('users')->insert(['role' => 'user']);` You're inserting a new user into DB with just `role` as field. `firstname` isn't set and doesn't have a default, that's why you get that error

Comment: @kerbholz how do I insert all the values then? Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: @user10341554 here you go :  array:11 [▼
  "_token" => "dT7jyI8wh8fbjpD4k1Cr8CAVNBDUMpWZZU9qmvyr"
  "firstname" => "ainsleys"
  "suffix" => "55238121"
  "lastname" => "kitchen"
  "city" => "Amsterdam"
  "zipcode" => "1123SD"
  "phoneNumber" => "0652482531"
  "streetName" => "peterstraat"
  "streetNumber" => "25"
  "email" => "ainsley@lol.com"
  "password" => "123456789"
]

Comment: Any reason for not using the Built-in authentication in Laravel?

Comment: Make `firstname` field required or set `firstname` field default to `NULL`

Comment: @VidhyutPandya in the form? and how do I do that?

Comment: `Form::text('firstname', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'required' => true])` and run this query ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `firstname` `firstname` VARCHAR(255)  NULL; FYI, it will allow `null` in your firstname field of the table.

Comment: I get no errors now, but still no data is given to the db. idk why

Answer (score 0):

replace this with your controller:

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    if(trim($request->password) == '')
    {
        $input = $request->except('password');

    }else{

        $input = $request->all();
    }
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    $input['role'] = 'user';

    User::create($input);

    return back()->with('success' , 'User is succesfully created');
}
```

Comment: still not inserting data in the db. it refreshes the page but doesn't give an error. very strange!

Comment: there is no error, like idk what to do. it should work? do you want to see my route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a value in the firstname-column. You do this the same way as with the role-column, just extend your array:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'role' => 'user',
    'firstname' => 'The First Name',
]);
```

The firstname column is nor marked as ->nullable() and therefore it always needs a value when you insert a row in that table.

Comment: isn't this line of code not doing that already? $input = $request->all();

Comment: ^ that line of code is only saving the user's request to a variable, it isn't doing anything with it

Answer (score 0):

```
**replace this method with your controller**

public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        $input['role'] = 'user';

        User::create($input);

        return back()->with('success' , 'User is succesfully created');
}
```

And Replace

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname','suffix','lastname', 'phoneNumber', 'role', 'streetName', 'streetNumber', 'city', 'zipcode' ,'email', 'password',
];

to 

 protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: did not help, still got no data in the db

Comment: but it isn't xddd idk why. no error only a page refresh and no data insertion in the db

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to insert all data to the database, instead update your controller as below and check it.

```
    public function store(UsersRequest $request){
    $user= New User([
            'firstname'         => $request->get('firstname'),
            'suffix'            => $request->get('suffix'),
            'lastname'          => $request->get('lastname'),
            'phoneNumber'       => $request->get('phoneNumber'),
            'role'              => $request->get('role'),
            'streetName'        => $request->get('streetName'),
            'city'              => $request->get('city'),
            'zipcode'           => $request->get('zipcode'),
            'email'             => $request->get('email'),
            'email_verified_at' => $request->get('email_verified_at'),
            'password'          => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->save();

        return back()->with('success' , 'User is succesfully created');

        }

}
```

Add validation if you want to use. Also, make sure your database is connected check .env file.

Comment: its still not working , no error no data passed in to the db.

Comment: Show us your Route

Comment: Show your web.php file